# Random populations of empty lists

Tags: python

I have to write a program in Python in which I give a range and a number of selections to append for 2 empty lists, so the approach of this program should be like this:

**Give range to select from:** 10

**Give number of selections:** 5

I should get:

**List of numbers selected randomly:** [2,3,7,1,8]

**List of numbers not selected:**  [4,6,5,9,10]

Numbers should not be repeated nor exist in both lists

I have this code:

```
import random
selected_list=[]
not_selected=[]
selecting_number=int(input('give range to select from : '))
select_num=int(input('give number of selections: '))
if selecting_number<select_num:
    print('error')
elif selecting_number>=select_num:
    for x in range(select_num):
        selected_list.append(random.randint(1,select_num))
    print(f'List of numbers selected randomly: {selected_list}')
    if not_selected not in selected_list:
        for y in range(select_num):
            not_selected.append(random.randint(1,select_num))
    print(f'List of numbers not selected previously: {not_selected}')
```

This is the output

```
List of numbers selected randomly: [6, 7, 7, 7, 7]

List of numbers not selected: [2, 4, 4, 8, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

What is causing the error is that `random` is picking random numbers independently and because they are random sometimes the same number is getting picked multiple times.

To fix this, you can use `random.sample(the_list_to_pick_from, number_to_pick)`
 From the docs:

> Returns a list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence
>   or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.

One implementation is this:

```
import random

range_to_pick_from = list(range(1,10))
selected = random.sample(x, 5)
not_selected = [a for a in range_to_pick_from if a not in selected]
print(selected,not_selected)
```

`not_selected` can also be written as a traditional for loop:

```
not_selected = []
for num in range_to_pick_from:
    if num not in selected:
        not_selected.append(num)
```

[Documentation for `random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Comment: if you could pleas add an alternative solutions

Comment: @andryjohnson Why?

Comment: @andryjohnson The imports are the same, and you can turn the list comprehension into a for loop if you want, what differences do you want? I have also fixed one of the variable names, give it a try now

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function to replicate this often and take in your parameters.

```
import random

def make_random_lists(my_range=10, selections=5):
    """
    Generate two lists of random numbers.

    INPUT
    ------
      my_range - (int)  how large the range we are selecting from
      selections - (int)  how many numbers should be in the list select list

    OUTPUT
    ------

      s - (list) the selected numbers
      ns - (list) not selected numbers
    """
    # make sure input values are valid
    if (selections < my_range):
        return "selections must be less than range", None
    if my_range <= 0:
        return "range must be larger than 0", None

    total_numbers = set(range(1, my_range+1))  # make range
    s = random.sample(total_numbers, k=selections)  # get selections
    ns = total_numbers - set(s)  # find those not used

    return s, list(ns)
```

You do not need to set a [seed](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.seed) unless you want to replicate your results with each run. Using sets to update your list is just another way to implement what is being done here! you could even combine the lines to make this more concise but this helps make it pretty clear.

Calling this function will yield the following results:

```
selected, not_selc = make_random_lists(12, 4) 
print(selected) 
print(not_selc)

>>>[7, 5, 3, 4]
>>>[1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

### Documentation

- [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set)
- [random](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html)
- [modules/functions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/modules.html)
- [Pyhton3 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: Dude... did you choose that seed to hide the bug? :-)

Comment: @HeapOverflow  What bug?

Comment: `choices` can repeat numbers. But your seed sweeps that under the rug. That rug really ties the room together.

Comment: @HeapOverflow thanks, changed to [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample) so the output is a unique list of values from population.

Comment: You shouldn't use assert to catch input errors. See Caveat #1: https://dbader.org/blog/python-assert-tutorial